# Not sure what context does an inner flow operate on

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I have a question about the context in which an inner flow produces

Consider the following code.

```
      withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
      {
        val flowA = flowOf(1,2,3,4)
        val flowB = flowOf("a","b","c")
        flowA.flatMapConcat { num->
          val bResponse = flowB.first() //would this operate on Dispatchers.Main OR IO
          flowOf(bResponse)
        }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
      }
    }
```

I have a nested flow and I am unsure on what context would the flowB.first() terminal operator operate on ?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow-on.html),

> `flowOn` changes the context where this flow is executed to the given context.

Since `val bResponse = flowB.first()` is executed inside `flowA`, its context is changed to `Dispatchers.IO` by the `flowOn` operator.